# Woocommerce product category template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I wanted to create a page template that is the same design as the woocommerce (please refer to the image below) product category template and display by category in my custom page template. How will start I am a newbie in woocommerce.

[default product category template design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiPdB.png)

Answer (score 0):

First create the page template in your theme's folder. Kindly check following steps.

1) Add **mynewtemplate.php** in your theme's folder.

2) Add `<?php /* Template Name: My new template*/ ?>` in newly created file. refer http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/ for more info.

3) At admin side add new page and choose `My new template` template.

4) You can add following codes in page editor.
There are list of short-codes are available.

```
 [woocommerce_product_filter] — shows a live Product Search Filter.
 [woocommerce_product_filter_attribute] — shows a live Product Attribute Filter.
 [woocommerce_product_filter_category] — shows a live Product Category Filter.
 [woocommerce_product_filter_price] — shows a live Product Price Filter.
 [woocommerce_product_filter_tag] —  shows a live Product Tag Filter.

 [product_category category="shirt"]  - Displayed `shirt` category product
```

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-product-search/shortcodes/ check for more info.

5) If you don't want to add this in page content area then add your code in **mynewtemplate.php**

```
<?php 

 do_shortcode( '[woocommerce_product_filter]' ); //— shows a live Product Search Filter.
 do_shortcode( '[woocommerce_product_filter_attribute]' ); //— shows a live Product Attribute Filter.
 do_shortcode( '[woocommerce_product_filter_category]' ); //— shows a live Product Category Filter.
 do_shortcode( '[woocommerce_product_filter_price]' ); //— shows a live Product Price Filter.
 do_shortcode( '[woocommerce_product_filter_tag]' ); //—  shows a live Product Tag Filter.

 do_shortcode( '[product_category category="shirt"]' ); // - Displayed `shirt` category product
 ?>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: So i need to install the extension WooCommerce Product Search?

Comment: I was thinking to create a template page and write a code on it. But I have no idea how to start.